# How I can access array elements of List

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, indexof

I have a question:

I have a List Java that I have populated with different values. For example, I have:

```
List<String[]> l = new ArrayList();
String[] lis = new String[3];
lis[0] = "A";
lis[1] = "B";
lis[2] = "C";
l.add(lis);
```

and I have other values too.
Now, I want to get the search in this list only the first field. For example, I want the A's indexOf.
I have tried to write this code:

```
int index = l.indexOf("A");
```

but I get -1 as return. I would like to know how I can access to a field of the list, when I load an array.

Comment: List is random insertion by default and searching is linear. So you have to search entire list and return if found the element

Comment: @Shriram No, lists are ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the A's indexOf.

No, you can't get it, since it is an element inside array. Array doesn't have indexOf method. List have that method.

> I would like to know how I can access to a field of the list, when I load an array.

```
String firstElem= l.get(0)[0];
```

get(0) gives you the first inserted array and [0] gives you the first positiend element in that array.

If you are looking for position of `A` in array, access the array from list with `l.get(0)` and iterate over the array you got to get the position of `A`.

**Update after comment:** If you have no idea of indexes you have

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l.get(i).length; j++) {
            if( l.get(i)[j].equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: Consider that as a example code and add checks for null's ,duplicates etc ...

Comment: My question is: if I don't know the index "0" (because I have a lof of data), how I can retrieve it on the based my first field?

Comment: @Musich87 In such cases you need to iterate over the list and again iterate over the array. Loop and an iner loop.

Comment: I have seen your update. I don't want the array index, but the list index. For example, if I have two arrays in my List "A", "B", "C" and "D", "E", "F" and I search "D", I want to retrieve the value 1 because it is the second array in my list. Your code is good if I change "return j" with "return i", right? Thanks Suresh

Comment: @Musich87 Exactly. :)  `return i`. Remember that, You'll get the result as a first index of the list , If duplicate entries are there in array. For ex : "D" and "D".

Comment: Yes, I want the first index of the value (for example "D") in the list. It's ok!

Answer (score 0):

You want do this :

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList();
String[] lis = new String[3];
lis[0] = "A";
lis[1] = "B";
lis[2] = "C";
l.addAll(lis);
```

Or you do not have to use array at all

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList();    
l.add("A");
l.add("B");
l.add("C");
```

In your case, you have list of arrays, not list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

after you `l.add(lis);` your list `l` has **only one single** element: `String[] lis`. **not n elements of the array**

you check if a String `"A"` in your list by `indexOf`, it returns -1, says, no I don't have that element.

You may want to check `Arrays.asList()` method, It converts an array into a `List`. I guess that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String[]> l = new ArrayList<>();
 String[] lis = new String[3];
 lis[0] = "A";
 lis[1] = "B";
 lis[2] = "C";
 l.add(lis); //  now your list have only one element and it's index is 0
```

You list don't have "`A`". So `l.indexOf("A")` will return `-1`

Where is "A" now?

```
l.get(0)[0] // l.get(0) is lis array. Then 0th element of lis is A
```

If you want to get index in this way you can use

```
String[] lis = new String[3];
lis[0] = "A";
lis[1] = "B";
lis[2] = "C";        

int index= Arrays.asList(lis).indexOf("A");
System.out.println(index);
```

Out put:

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `List` contains String *arrays* (`String[]`). I think what you meant to do was to create a `List<String>`.

If you truly want a `List<String[]>`, then your code would look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    String[] array = list.get(i);
    for(String s : array)
    {
        if("A".equals(s))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```